# How to solve a linear system in java

Tags: java

```
public Point intersects(Line line) {
    Line holder = new Line(slope, yintercept);
    double x;
    double y;
    if (Math.abs(slope - line.slope) < 0.0000000001) {
        return null;
// because can't be parallel and if they don't intercept it has to return null
    } else {
        //no clue what to do here
        y = (holder.slope*x+yintercept);
    }
    Point interception = new Point(x, y);
    return interception;
```

I don't know how to figure what x would be equal to thanks for help in advance

Comment: This seems more like a math question than anything.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Did `Math.abs` make it so obvious :-) ?

Comment: Make a variable `private static final double EPSILON =  0.0000000001;` it will looks my better.

Comment: @Carcigenicate it's not the math part of it that's bothering me its the part where try to put that math into code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this version with f(x) = m * x + c ...

```
class LineIntersectException extends Exception
{
    LineIntersectException(String message)
    {
        super(message);
    }
}

public static Point intersect(Line line1, Line line2)
{
    if(line1.m == line2.m)
    {
        throw new LineIntersectException("The two lines don't intersect");
    }

    double x = (line1.c - line2.c) / (line1.m - line2.m);
    double y = this.m * x + this.b;

    return new Point(x, y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have `L1 = ax + c` and `L2 = bx + d` (a and b are the slopes and c and d are intercepts).
At the point where lines intersects `L1 = L2` so `ax + c = bx + d`, then
`ax - bx = d - c`  so `x = (d-c)/(a-b)`.
If we want to find y then use calculated above x and we have:
`y = a * ((d-c)/(a-b) + c`,
hence the point of intersection is:

```
P((d-c)/(a-b), (ad-bc)/(a-b))
```